# find numeric exists in a string

Tags: php, search, find

```
$st1='sdfsffgfgfdgf4324csadsaffas34df'
$st2='saddsd56856785 dfdffffv'
$st3='fdasfdsfdsfdsfdsfdffd'
```

How to find numeric, exist in a string?

in the above, st1, st2 contain numeric

Comment: So basically any string that contains at least one digit fits the description. Did you try to determine that?

Comment: Questions shouldn't be downvoted just because you think the answer is easy. Not everyone is at the same skill level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]/', $st1, $matches);
return !empty($matches); // returns true if there is a number in $st1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `preg_match`

```
if (preg_match('/\d/', $str)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
$result = preg_match('/[0-9]/', $st1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ereg_replace`](https://www.php.net/ereg_replace). This function scans string for matches to pattern, then replaces the matched text with replacement.

```
<?php
$ms="String321";
$string = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$ms);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: ereg functions are depreciated now, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsNumeric($str) {
    preg_match("/\\d/", $str, $matches);
    return !empty($matches);
}

echo containsNumeric("ab2c"); // true
```